# Lista enlazada. Null pointer Exception Java

Tags: java, excepciones

Deseo agregar un último elemento a una lista enlazada. Lo que hago es moverme por los elementos de la lista hasta el ultimo. Una vez allí, realizo una instancia del nuevo elemento y hago que el último elemento de la lista apunte a este nuevo.

Éste es el método que agrega un elemento al final de la lista, el color es el único atributo de cada nodo (le llamo `vagones`):

```
public void agregarAlFinal(String color){

    Vagon aux=this.primero; //creo una referencia aux para pasar de vagon a vagon hasta llegar al ultimo
    while(aux!=null){  //cuando la referencia apunte al nulo entonces es porque estamos al final de la lista
            aux=aux.getSiguiente();
    }    
    Vagon v=new Vagon(color); //creo una referencia a un vagon para colocarlo al final  (instancio un nuevo nodo)         
    aux.setSiguiente(v);//ahora el ultimo nodo apunta al recien creado
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te muestro el problema en tu propio código:

```
public void agregarAlFinal(String color){

    Vagon aux=this.primero; 
    while(aux!=null){  // aca le estas diciendo que termine el bucle cuando aux sea nulo
            aux=aux.getSiguiente();
    }    
    Vagon v=new Vagon(color);     
    aux.setSiguiente(v);//esto no puede realizarse porque aux es nulo(por eso el null pointer exception)
}
```

Para solucionarlo solo tienes que cambiar la condición del bucle para que quede así:

```
public void agregarAlFinal(String color){

    Vagon aux=this.primero;
    while(aux.getSiguiente()!=null){  //asi se queda con el ultimo valor antes del null
            aux=aux.getSiguiente();
    }    
    Vagon v=new Vagon(color);   
    aux.setSiguiente(v);
}
```

Comment: Genio mil gracias!!